# Filter an array based on values from another array with same length

Tags: javascript

I'm given an array of objects representing data about people. I need to filter names, which when add the ASCII representation of all characters in their first names, the result will be an odd number.
**e.g.: Sum of ASCII codes of letters in 'Aba' is: 65 + 98 + 97 = 260 which is an even number** -- filter it out

**My logic is as follows:**

1. get first names;
2. convert each letter of the first name to ASCII code;
3. add ASCII codes of each name;
4. check, if the received number is odd;
5. return names, which ASCII code number is odd.

I've completed 4 tasks of the above, but I do not know, how to connect items from different arrays. 
E.g.: I have an array of names: `let names = ['Aba', 'Abb']`, and array of odd/even numbers: `let oddEven = [0, 1]`.

**How can I make:**

1) names[0] is oddEven[0]

2) if oddEven[0] > 0 { filter it out } ?

Thanks

my code:

```
function findOddNames(list) {

  let names = list.map((name) => name.firstName);
  let splittedNames = names.map((name) => name.split(''));
  let charCodes = splittedNames.map((arr) => arr.map((letter) => letter.charCodeAt(0)));
  let charCodesTotal = charCodes.map((arr) => arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0));
  let oddEven = charCodesTotal.map((item) => item % 2);    
};

findOddNames([
  { firstName: 'Aba', lastName: 'N.', country: 'Ghana', continent: 'Africa', age: 21, language: 'Python' },
  { firstName: 'Abb', lastName: 'O.', country: 'Israel', continent: 'Asia', age: 39, language: 'Java' }
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** like this. `oddEven` has the modulo values. Just `filter` the indexes from `names` array which have non-zero `oddEven` values. To get even values, use `oddEven[i] === 0`

```js
function findOddNames(list) {
  let names = list.map((name) => name.firstName);
  let splittedNames = names.map((name) => name.split(''));
  let charCodes = splittedNames.map((arr) => arr.map((letter) => letter.charCodeAt(0)));
  let charCodesTotal = charCodes.map((arr) => arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0));
  let oddEven = charCodesTotal.map((item) => item % 2);
  let oddNames = names.filter((n, i) => oddEven[i] !== 0)
  return oddNames;
};

const odd = findOddNames([
  { firstName: 'Aba', lastName: 'N.', country: 'Ghana', continent: 'Africa', age: 21, language: 'Python' },
  { firstName: 'Abb', lastName: 'O.', country: 'Israel', continent: 'Asia', age: 39, language: 'Java' }
])

console.log(odd)
```

Comment: unbelievable!! Thank you very much!) By the way, could you please explain, what does _, mean?

Comment: @an_bozh sorry for adding that there. It's just a parameter name. You can use `n` or `name`

Comment: I'm accepting your answer, because it answers my question. Other solutions are better than mine, but they are not mine. I need to show my own solution. I'm not able to write code the way @NickParsons and Ele do. Great practice, a lot of useful information. Thank you all very much

Answer (score 0):

This alternative uses the function `filter` to get only odd names and the function `reduce` to sum the ASCII code for each letter, and finally the operator `%` to check if the sum is even or odd.

```js
let findOddNames = (arr) => {
  return arr.filter(({firstName}) => {
    return firstName.split('').reduce((a, letter) => letter.charCodeAt(0) + a, 0) % 2;
  });
};

let result = findOddNames([
  { firstName: 'Aba', lastName: 'N.', country: 'Ghana', continent: 'Africa', age: 21, language: 'Python' },
  { firstName: 'Abb', lastName: 'O.', country: 'Israel', continent: 'Asia', age: 39, language: 'Java' }
]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead without creating separate arrays to hold each variation of your input array.

Below, I have used `.filter` to filter out your input array into your `findOddNames` array. If you want to keep a given element when  using filter, you need to return `true`, if you don't want to keep it (ie sum of the `firstName` is even) then you can return `false`.

In the filter function, I have also made use of [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), which allows me to easily pull out the `firstName` property from your input array. I have also used the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). This is an easy way to convert a string of characters, into an array of characters. Finally, I used [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) on the array to get the sum of all the characters in the array.

See example below:

```js
const findOddNames = arr => {
  return arr.filter(({firstName:n}) => {
    const sum = [...n].reduce((acc, letter) => acc + letter.charCodeAt(0), 0);
    return sum % 2 !== 0;  
  });
}

console.log(findOddNames([
  { firstName: 'Aba', lastName: 'N.', country: 'Ghana', continent: 'Africa', age: 21, language: 'Python' },
  { firstName: 'Abb', lastName: 'O.', country: 'Israel', continent: 'Asia', age: 39, language: 'Java' }
]));
```